# CMake: Check existence of MSVC compiler flags

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

Normally, I use `check_cxx_compiler_flag` to check whether a given flag is recognized by the currently used compiler. However, I have run into issues with MSVC where some default flags are causing the test to fail due to incompatible flags.

MWE:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(MWE)

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)

check_cxx_compiler_flag("/O2" FLAG_USABLE)

if (NOT FLAG_USABLE)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Flag not usable")
endif()
```

When this is run on Windows in a developer command prompt, the test fails and the error log contains

```
Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe cmTC_e3d37.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /v:m && MSBuild version 17.3.1+2badb37d1 for .NET Framework

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.33.31630 for x64

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  cl /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /O2 /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D FLAG_USABLE /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_e3d37.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_e3d37.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W1 /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "D:\a\cmake-compiler-flags\cmake-compiler-flags\test\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\src.cxx"

cl : command line  error D8016: '/O2' and '/RTC1' command-line options are incompatible
```

which clearly shows that the flag *is* recognized, but it just does not play nicely with the `/RTC1` flag, which somehow still gets added to the build.

How can I get rid of these default options (or at least all that are not essential for a build to complete), regardless of the used build configuration, so that my test really checks whether the compiler understands the given flag?

Comment: For this particular issue using `set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION "Release")` fixes the issue. But my assumption is that this only works for this specific option and if one wanted to e.g. test whether `/RTC1` was supported, one would end up with the same issues.

Comment: Related, but sadly unanswered: https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2017-December/066682.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess your IDE - Visual Studio is adding this compilation flag. Try running Cmake from command line and the problem should be solved. In order to change VS behavior go to `Solution -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Basic Runtime Checks` and change the value of this flag to `default` or disabled.

Comment: I _am_ running cmake from the command-line